# Exponential decrease of amplitude with time

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function

I was wondering about a particular math problem.

It says that a particular trigonometric function, $10 \cos(2\pi x)$ models a bus going over a speed bump.

They say that the amplitude decreases over time, such that at the $x=0$ second, the amplitude is $10$ and at the first second $x=1$, the amplitude is $8$. They ask to create an exponential function just of the amplitude change, which I presume is $10 \cdot 0.8^x$.

However, they then say to use this equation to model the same cosine equation to ensure that the amplitude changes exponentially with respect to time. I thought that this would be the equation: 
$$10 \cdot 0.8^x \cdot \cos(2\pi x) \ ,$$
however, when I check this equation in a graph, the graph doesn't look correct.

Am I on the right track? If not, I really would appreciate all of the help I can get! Thanks so much!

Comment: Wlecome to Math.ME. Since you're using the cosine, it means that at time $x=0$ seconds the bus is at the highest point in the bump. Was that intended? By the way, if you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) the equations will look nicer.

Answer (score 1):

The graph is below.  What doesn't look right about it?  The peaks decrease exponentially like you want.  As the period is $2$, each peak is $0.64$ of the one before of the same sign.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! For some reason, when I plot it, it looks like this. For the equation you graphed:

Comment: How would I make a graph whose amplitude decreases by a factor of .8 each time?

Comment: You can have the period be $1$, so make it $0.8^x\cos(2 \pi x)$.  Alternately, if you want the period to stay $2$, you want $0.8^{x/2}\cos (\pi x)$ so it decreases by a factor $0.8$ in $2$ units of time.

Comment: I tried that, however, it seems almost as if the entire graph shifts. Like when I try to even put .8^x*cos(pix), everything seems to be king of messed up. For example, between -1 and 1, the highest point isn't 1, but it's actually 1.0025, and then decreases by a factor of .8 after that. So instead of being 1(.8)^x, it is now becoming 1.0025(.8)^x, and I have no idea why it's doing that. When I simply put .8cospix, it is clear that it is starting out at a high of .8, but then as soon as I put in the exponential function, it creates some odd decimal...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tag your username above.

Comment: There is something wrong with the software you are using or how you are using it.  $.8^0\cos(0)=1$.  When it computes $0.8^x$ it is probably doing $e^{(x \log (0.8))}$, which won't come out exactly but there is no excuse for being that far off.  Specifically for $e^0$ you should get a good $1$.

Comment: So the equation, 10(.8)^x * cos(2pix) is perfectly good for a cosine graph which has an amplitude of 10 first, and then decreases its amplitude exponentially by a factor of .8 after each period? Weird. I am using Desmos, and the above of what I mentioned is what is happening. Specifically, I am inputting 8^x*cos(pix). Sure enough, the highest point between -1 and 1 is 1.0025. Weirdly enough, the y intercept is (0,1), but yeah, the amplitude is showing as 1.0025, and then it exponentially decreases by .8. Am I doing something drastically wrong? I'm worried now...

Comment: The high point will be higher than $1$ and will occur for a small negative value of $x$.  The cosine is flat at $0$ but $0.8^x$ is not and that will shift the peak.  I find the maximum to be about $1.0025$ as you do at $x$ about $-0.025$

Comment: If you had specifically said what was wrong initially it would have been much easier to find the problem.  Instead you just said it doesn't look right.

Comment: So this is natural? Is there any way to solve this problem so it is exact, as you were indicating beforehand?

Comment: So sorry about the confusion before!

Comment: When you multiply a sine or cosine with an exponential, the peaks are not at the same time as the peaks in the sine or cosine wave.  Recall the product rule for the derivative $(0.8^x \cos (\pi x))'=(0.8^x)'\cos(\pi x)+0.8^x(\cos(\pi x))'$.  The derivative of cosine is $0$ at the peak, but the value is $1$.  The derivative will not be $0$ at $x=0$ because of the first term.  In this case you have to go to slightly negative $x$ to get the derivative to be zero.

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you think my original answer, that is 10(.8)^x * cos(2pix) is sufficient to answer the question, that is, to create a trigonometric function which exponentially decreases its amplitude by .8?

Comment: Yes, that is what they are looking for.